# Are there security concerns with Bluetooth low energy?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

In the first versions of BLE specifications, there was a huge security flaw during the pairing allowing an attacker to perform a MITM attack. Since Bluetooth 4.2, the pairing use ECDH, so there isn't left much to worry (I guess...). I search for other security flaws, but even if I often read that Bluetooth (so BLE too) is not secure, I didn't find anything really interesting with the latests versions of the protocol.

There are some issue regarding privacy ([for example](https://stanfy.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-security-issues-and-how-to-overcome-them/)), but is it still the case for the security?

Comment: I don't think so: the attack described uses the flaw in the initial pairing that has been corrected with Bluetooth 4.2. Now, with the use of ECDH it is (theorically) impossible to gain knowledge about the keys, even by eavesdropping the initial pairing.

Comment: https://github.com/securing/gattacker